# TextView is returning null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

I have a listener that simply changes a button's text and clocks the time for the user. I also have a textview that is supposed to change to the new total amount of time worked when the user clocks out. I double checked the xml to make sure I was grabbing the right R.Id and the button in the listener is being found just not the TextView. Here is the code:

```
public class HoursListener implements OnClickListener{

GlobalApp appState;
Button startStopHoursButton;
TextView hoursTotalTextView;
public boolean clockedIn;

public HoursListener(Context ctx){
    appState = ((GlobalApp)ctx.getApplicationContext());
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    startStopHoursButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.hourstogglebutton);
    hoursTotalTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.totalWorktimeTextView);
    if(!clockedIn){
        startStopHoursButton.setText(R.string.clockout);
        appState.getCurrentCompany().getCurrentNewWeeklyTimestamp().CreateFinishTimeStamp();
        clockedIn = true;
    }else{
        startStopHoursButton.setText(R.string.clockin);
        appState.getCurrentCompany().getCurrentNewWeeklyTimestamp().CreateFinishTimeStamp();
        clockedIn = false;
        hoursTotalTextView.setText(appState.getCurrentCompany().getCurrentNewWeeklyTimestamp().totalTimeDoneThisWeekToString());                
    }
}
```

}

Heres the xml for the textView:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalWorktimeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
```

The error is with this line:

```
hoursTotalTextView.setText(appState.getCurrentCompany().getCurrentNewWeeklyTimestamp().totalTimeDoneThisWeekToString());
```

I was thinking about just putting the code in the activity itself but I feel like I can do it this way. I want something I can call like a listener so I reduce the redundancy in my code. I have double checked that it is the hoursTotalTextView that is null. Yet the button isn't. Any ideas?

Screenshot of Eclipse (linked to full-size version) showing that the relevant values aren't null:
[image: Screenshot of Eclipse]

Comment: its my application class I have for static variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the onClickListener whose click you are listening to is the button? The onClick passes the View v that was clicked - i.e. the button - and the textbox is not a child of the button, so you can't find it.

If HoursListener is declared inside your activity, just do findViewById instead of v.findViewById i.e.

```
hoursTotalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalWorktimeTextView);
```

If not, pass the textview into the HoursListener constructor and set hoursTotalTextView there (bearing in mind this feels like it might cause memory leaks).

Comment: All I needed was to pass the TextView to the listener. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

what is GlobalApp appState; and why you are typecasting context to GlobalApp from below line.
I think appstate will be null here.

appState = ((GlobalApp)ctx.getApplicationContext());

if GlobalApp is a class then create a object for it and then use getter and setter methods.

Comment: GlobalApp is my application I made so I can access certain static variables needed for my app to run.

Comment: can you paste that class because i am confused with this line  appState.getCurrentCompany().getCurrentNewWeeklyTimestamp().CreateFinishTimeStamp();

Comment: as in extending class Application?u need to refine your code either GlobalApp  or TextView may be null ....

Comment: I'll explain it. App state has a current company that has a list of weeklyTimestamps. Those weeklytimestamps hold timestamps for that week and GetCurrentNewWeeklyTimestamps() either gets you this weeks time stamp or creates a new one for this week. CreateFinishTimestamp either starts a new timestamp or finishes one that is already created.

Comment: Vincent - yes and TextView is null. GlobalApp is not null or I would be throwing nullpointers everywhere in the listener. The textView is the only thing saying its null.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
startStopHoursButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.hourstogglebutton);
hoursTotalTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.totalWorktimeTextView);
```

some where before,can be constructor cause your setText is working on null TextView object.

Comment: I have that whenever the onClick method is called.

Comment: try keepin it in constructor coz your textView is null or may be using wrong xml i guess...

Answer (score 0):

Check each object in that line

```
if(appState.getCurrentCompany()==null)
     Log.d("","getCurrentCompany is null");
if(appState.getCurrentCompany().getCurrentNewWeeklyTimestamp()==null)
     Log.d("","getCurrentNewWeeklyTimestamp is null");
if(appState.getCurrentCompany().getCurrentNewWeeklyTimestamp().totalTimeDoneThisWeekToString()==null)
     Log.d("","totalTimeDoneThisWeekToString is null");
```

Comment: all of those are not null. Debug shows that the TextView is null.

Comment: you should also note that your mainview is null too. Can you provide how MainActivity is creating HoursListener? And Is main.xml the only xml? Generally, TextView should be in Activity class. Please provide MainActivity.java too.